# Having problems with reverse proxy with nginx and Blazor Webassembly

Tags: nginx, blazor, blazor-webassembly, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have an application in blazor webassembly with serves several customers.

My pages are of this type:

`@page "/{id:int}"`

Where id is the customer Id. Every page is served for every customer.

Now, every customer accesses with their own domain or subdomain, so my nginx is something like this (suppose this is the customer number 6)

```
        listen 80;
        server_name mydomain.com;

        location / {
                rewrite ^/$ /6 permanent;
                proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:5139;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 80;
        }
}
```

Obviously this is not working (this is someway working, but it is showing /6 in the navigator), this is one of a lot of tries i've done. What I need is that when customer enters in http://example.com, sees and only sees http://127.0.0.1:5139/6 and the rest. For example:

http://example.com/order should map to http://127.0.0.1:5139/6/order and so on....

Also i need to be able to load the static content of Blazor Webassembly, _content, _framework,etc. that is common to everyone of else.

What can I do?